# Запись и чтение из удаленных директорий

Tags: php, remote-access

Есть несколько серверов(логические) на которых лежат только скрипты и несколько серверов(транспортые) на которых будут распологаться медиа файлы.

Запросы на API будут поступать с транспортных серверов на логические, которые в свою очередь должны записить или считать медиа с транспортных серверов. Записать и считать нужно с того же сервера с которого пришел запрос.

Какими инструментами достигаются подобные решения? Первое что пришло на ум использовать FTP в php, но может есть варианты получше!

**UPDATE**:
Погуглив нашел решение монтировать медиа разделы с транспортых серверов на логические. Теперь проблема заключается в том как правильно мониторить доступность монтированного раздела и в случае недоступности монтировать раздел со следующего доступного транспорт сервера

Comment: Не очень понятно что будет обрабатывать запросы на транспортных серверах, да и в общем всё вместе не особенно понятно. PHP здесь каким боком используется? Распишите более подробно и конкретно, что, где и как, желательно с примерами.

Comment: На транспортных серверах стоит Asterisk который обрабатывает поступающие звонки абонентов и дает им возможность записать голосовое сообщение. Обработку и запись выполняет ядро которое написаное на php и находится на логическом сервере.

Comment: Тогда нужно исходить из того как вообще организован доступ от сервера Х на сервер У. Если обычный folder sharing, то и FTP не нужен.